# Как разрешить вывод на страницу div только с определенным классом?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть `div`, в котором автоматически меняются классы (функцией, в зависимости от города пользователя). Каким образом можно разрешить вывод `div`-а только если у него `class="he"`? В других остальных случаях `div` не должен отображаться на странице. Через `css` и `display:none` не вариант. Нужно вовсе что бы он и в коде не отображался.

Вот как формируются классы:

```
<div class='
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo $details->country; // -> "Mountain View"
?>
'></div>
```

Comment: @br3t не совсем понимаю логику )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
if($details->country == 'he') {
    print("<div class='he'>".$product->get_price_html()."</div>");
}
```

Comment: Работает. Но внутри не могу функцию вставить, крашится верстка.
 print("<div class='he'><?php echo ($product->get_price_html()); ?></div>");

Comment: Поправил под ваши нужды